# Convert Yaml file into SOAPUI project from command line or using any scripts

Tags: xml, powershell, cmd, yaml, soapui

Is there way to convert Yaml file into soapUI project from command line or using any scripts. Its basically XML, something like below.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<con:soapui-project id="cb41c3bf-84c6-4e1c-adc7-b6878ae12368" created="3.43.1" activeEnvironment="Default environment" name="api name" projectVersion="" updated="3.43.1 2023-01-25T13:44:53Z" xmlns:con="http://eviware.com/soapui/config">
  <con:settings/>
  <con:interface xsi:type="con:RestService" id="98202ab7-05d3-468b-a184-b55e72f41b4b" name="api name [api/name]" type="rest_ex" wadlVersion="https://swagger.io/openapiv3/specification" definitionUrl="file:/C:/Users/xxx/Downloads/Sec%20Ecu%20APIs%20%5Bsec_ecudr%5D.openapi%20(1).yaml" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <con:description xsi:nil="true"/>
    <con:settings/>
    <con:definitionCache type="TEXT" rootPart="file:/C:/Users/xxx/Downloads/Sec%20Ecu%20APIs%20%5Bsec_ecudr%5D.openapi%20(1).yaml">
      <con:part>
        <con:url>file:/C:/Users/xxxx/Downloads/Sec%20Ecu%20APIs%20%5Bsec_ecudr%5D.openapi%20(1).yaml</con:url>
        <con:content>openapi: 3.0.1
```

Comment: You can use any scripting language that supports both YAML and XML for this. This question is too general, you should try to implement it and then come back here with problems you encounter while doing so.

Comment: I am not seeing any hints how to convert the Yaml into readyAPI(SOAPUI) xml project to run this xml file from our azure ADO pipeline